# сколько существует натуральных чисел n меньше 1000 для которых 2^n n делится на 7

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,i; 
    cout<<"Enter the number : "; 
    cin>>n; 
    for(i=1;i<1000;i++){ 
    if(n%7==0) 
    cout<<n<<" ";
    } 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2^nn - это что? 2 в степени n в квадрате, n умноженное на 2 в степени n?...

Comment: @Harry  это 2^n. n делится на 7

Comment: [это 2^n. n делится на 7] Понятнее не стало. :-)

Comment: Все равно ни хрена не понял. Одно предложение - "это 2^n" Второе - "n делится на 7". Так что ищем? :) А, в любом случае - закрывать надо по причине "учебный вопрос, ничего не делал самостоятельно"...

Comment: Угу, предложение кажется бессмысленным. *"сколько существует натуральных чисел n меньше 1000 для которых 2^n (2^n - что?). n делится на 7"*

Comment: Что ж тут бессмысленного? :) Понятно же, что условие можно записать так: `if (2**n && (n % 7 == 0)) ...` (не уверен, что степень в Си записывается именно так, но не суть важно), что очевидно, эквивалентно `n % 7 == 0` для любого натурального `n`. Ну а дальше см. ответ @Qwertiy.

Comment: @Harry, код появился.

Comment: @Harry да код появился но я не получил правильного ответа. помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @bijou Так от Вас тут уже три часа пытаются добиться, что означает загадочная формулировка "для которых 2^n.", а воз и ныне там.

Comment: Что толку с непонятного кода, если **непонятно само условие**. Будет ТЗ - будем говорить, а пока - ХЗ...

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  puts("142");
}
```

Comment: Стоит ли отвечать на столь низкокачественные вопросы?